# How to convert pathogen installation instructions to vundle?

Tags: vim, pathogen, vundle

I use Vundle to manage my plugins.  However, some plugins only have instructions for manual installation or installation with Pathogen. For example:

> **install details**
>
> Installation With Pathogen:
>
> ```
>   1. Place in pathogen directory
> ```
>
> Installation W/Out Pathogen:
>
> ```
>   1. Place in .vim/indent directory, or anywhere in your runtime path.
>   2. If placed outside of .vim/indent directory, 
>          set g:js_indent = /location/to/javascript.vim in your
>         .vimrc file. (This tells the html.vim file where to find
>         the javascript indent file)
> ```
>
> ***Source***: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081

Is there a way to convert Pathogen installation instructions to work with Vundle?

Or should I have both Pathogen and Vundle installed and use which ever one seems best supported by the Plugin I want to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pathogen just extends your `'runtimepath'` to include separate plugin directories under `~/.vim/bundle/...` (but doesn't care how you install the plugins there). Later, plugins like Vundle copied that idea and added functionality to automatically update from GitHub and other locations.

As long as you have an install location that is supported by Vundle, it should be trivial to consume it. For the mentioned plugin, this should be (using the vim-scripts.org GitHub mirror):

```
Plugin 'JavaScript-Indent'
```

#### Summary

You don't need explicit instructions from a plugin to install it via a plugin manager. As long as the install location is supported, just follow [Vundle's quick start](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim#quick-start). Vundle offers a superset of Pathogen; you'll never need both.